# Error al hacer include en NodeJs con Sequelize

Tags: nodejs, sequelize.js

estoy haciendo una solicitud por id a mi tabla Users y le pido que me traiga otras tablas asociadas con include, dejare un ejemplo donde podran ver que parece estar todo correcto

```
            const result = await Users.findByPk(id, {
                attributes: ["id", "nombre", "apellido", "correo", "rolId"],
                include: {
                    model: Vivienda,
                    as: "uservivienda",
                    attributes: ["id", "nombre", "nroCasa", "telefono", "numero", "etapa", "sector", "casa", "calle", "recibospendientes", "deudadl", "deudabs", "status"],
                    include: {
                        model: Recibo,
                        as: "viviendaRecibo",
                        attributes: ["id", "totalpagar", "montomes", "saldoanterio", "interesmora", "meses"],
                        include: {
                            model: ReciboModelo,
                            as: "reciboRecibomodelo",
                            attributes: ["id", "Fecha", "bcv"],
                            include: [{
                                model: Gastos,
                                as: "recibomodeloGastos",
                                attributes: ["id", "nombre", "Fecha", "ncasa", "monto"],
                            }]
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

pero no me trae la informacion completa ese codigo ya que me excluye **recibomodeloGastos**. ejemplo del resultado que me arroja el API

```
"uservivienda": {
"id": 1,
"nombre": "Servio Flores",
"nroCasa": "1-B-3",
"telefono": "2123417046",
"numero": "4129578938",
"etapa": "1",
"sector": "B",
"casa": "3",
"calle": "1",
"recibospendientes": null,
"deudadl": null,
"deudabs": null,
"status": null,
"viviendaRecibo": [
{
"id": 1,
"totalpagar": null,
"montomes": 10.37,
"saldoanterio": null,
"interesmora": 1,
"meses": 0,
"reciboRecibomodelo": {
"id": 21,
"Fecha": "2023-09-20",
"bcv": 33.8333
}
```

cuando hago el llamdo de ReciboModelo directamente al id si me trae la informacion completa con su  asociado que seria gastos. ejemplo de mi codigo y el resultado que me arroja el API

```
            const result = await ReciboModelo.findByPk(id,{
                attributes:["id", "Fecha", "bcv"],
                include:{
                    model: Gastos,
                    as: "recibomodeloGastos",
                    attributes:["id", "nombre", "Fecha", "ncasa", "monto"]
                }
            })
            return result;
```

API

```
{
"id": 21,
"Fecha": "2023-09-20",
"bcv": 33.8333,
"recibomodeloGastos": [
{
"id": 42,
"nombre": "Servicio Valle Arriba",
"Fecha": "2023-09-12",
"ncasa": "",
"monto": 300
},
{
"id": 43,
"nombre": "Bolsas basura",
"Fecha": "2023-09-04",
"ncasa": "",
"monto": 2000
}
]
}
```

Alguien podria ayudarme y decirme porque pasa esto, realmente he intentado de todo y no consigo el porque, muchas gracias!